# Appium Codeceptjs iOS tap on text

Tags: ios, testing, automated-tests, appium, codeceptjs

With `Appium` `Codeceptjs` it is possible to tap on text with Android.

```
I.tap('OK')
```

How to make this tap work for iOS build?

This native function is not working on iOS.

https://codecept.io/mobile/

Comment: Have you tried [runOnIOS](https://codecept.io/helpers/Appium.html#runonios) with `I.click()`? Also you could take a look if [makeTouchAction](https://codecept.io/helpers/Appium.html#maketouchaction) works on iOS.

Comment: @balintpekker I.click() is not working for native builds. Touch is not reliable because it takes screen coordinates as params